# Perform Math.Floor on BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, aws-documentdb

Our team is migrating to AWS DocumentDB from MongoDB. We noticed that there are arithmetic operators such as `$ceil` and `$floor` that are [not supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-aggregation-pipeline-arithmetic) by DocumentDB.

At the moment, I am trying to perform `Math.Ceiling` in code instead of using the `$ceil` operator. This is the original query:

```
var result = new BsonDocument("$ceil", new BsonDocument("$divide", new BsonArray { { "$totalCount.total" }, { pageSize } }));
```

I am trying to perform the ceiling operation in code like that:

```
var result Math.Ceiling(new BsonDocument("$divide", new BsonArray { { "$totalCount.total" }, { pageSize } })).AsDouble);
```

But I am getting an error stating that the cast do double is not possible

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDouble'.
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue.get_AsDouble()
   at Rushmore.Data.API.Logic.WellLogic.PagingStage(Int32 page, Int32 pageSize) in D:\_Code\...WellLogic.cs:line 88
   at Rushmore.Data.API.Logic.WellLogic.PagedWellIdsWithoutFilter(Reviews review, String idField, Int32[] filterIds, Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 pageSize) in D:\_Code\...\WellLogic.cs:line 195
   at Rushmore.Data.API.Logic.WellLogic.GetPagedCollectionData(Reviews review, String idField, String collectionName, IReviewQueryOptions queryOptions, Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 pageSize, String filter) in D:\_Code\DataAPI\Rushmore.Data.API\Logic\WellLogic.cs:line 537
   at Rushmore.Data.API.Controllers.WellsController.DPRTDData(Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 pageSize, String lengthUnits) in D:\_Code\...WellsController.cs:line 31
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
```

What am I missing here? What is the correct syntax to perform ceiling operation?

Comment: I know very little about `C#`, `.NET`, AWS DocumentDB, but I'm wondering if you need [`ToDouble`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonValue_ToDouble.htm).  FYI, your "original query" uses `"$floor"`.

Comment: Thank you for your commendation. I accidentally used the wrong code. I have corrected that now. I will try using the `ToDouble` method

Comment: I tried to use the `ToDouble` method but I am getting a cast exception as well. I have updated my question to include the exception message I am getting with the `AsDouble` property as well.

Comment: The error message for `...ToDouble()` is the same?